# How to edit the flat.aspx page include other discussion board column values?

Tags: data-view-web-part, discussion-board, aspx

Any ideas on how to modify the flat.aspx page used for the discussion board list in order to show other data from other columns?

I have added a lookup column to the discussion board pointing to the ID column of a document library. My intention is to make the discussions document specific. This works well (for generating document relevant emails etc.) except for the inability to see the lookup column value when replying to or viewing a discussion.

My guess is inserting the data view Webpart, but not sure were or what to do after.

Answer (score 2):

In Discussion Board for storing questions (Body field in Discussion Content Types) and answers (Body field in Message Content Type)  is used Enhanced Rich Text field that allows to upload files and insert file links.

So, `Upload file` RTE command could be used to upload files into Documents library and insert links into questions and answers in Discussion Board.

### How to Upload document and insert document link into Discussion item

- Create a new discussion item
- For answer (body) select `Insert` Tab and `Upload File` button in
  Ribbon menu

[image]

### Results

Discussion view
[image]

Comment: Thanks Vadim. This is good suggestion but it does not achieve the objective of being able to discuss documents that users are currently collaborating on. Following your method it would be better to use the `Link` RTE command. I would like the document discussion process to be simpler, for users to enter the document ID which allows custom workflow emails to reference the document (which is easy enough) and (which is my issue) for the document link to appear in the discussion thread.

Comment: [This dev center blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ac87969c-5880-4fca-b796-f4645dd296a0/how-to-allow-users-accessing-attachments-directly-in-a-discussion-board-list-without-clicking-view?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) shows a good solution for a similar goal, but I cannot figure out how to change the code accordingly and where to insert it into the flat.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same goal and we've solved it simply.

Assuming you have a default Doc library and a default Discussion Board.

1. Add a custom lookup column to Discussion board which uses Doc library as the data source.
2. Create a web part page (aka "wiki page" in SP 2013) in two-cloumn design and add the Doc library app in the left column. Save the page.
3. Edit the page again. Select the Doc lib web part, open the "Web part" section of ribbon, click "Insert a linked list" and select "Discussion board" item.
4. Move the Discussion board web part to the right part of the page.
5. Save the page.

*Voila!*